# What is the formula for measuring Antenna range?

Tags: antenna

According to example 1 of this [website](https://thefactfactor.com/facts/pure_science/physics/antenna/5117/)

The formula for measuring the antenna range is this => D = radical(2hR)
which R is 6400km for earth and h is the height of our antenna from ground.

So if we have a tower that has 100 meter height,the maximum coverage range for this tower is about 35.77km.

My question is , what is the coverage range of the specific antenna? for example yaggi , horn , dipole , parabolic reflector with ... 
The formula above is just for the tower range, not for the antenna of specific frequency and gain.

Comment: you might be looking for the Friis equation.

Comment: @BrianDrummond i found this link , is this correct? https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/wireless-range/

Comment: When you talk about tower range you seem to be thinking about a line of sight connection. This is not necessarily required for communication.

Comment: The formula you posted is the distance to the horizon, from a height h above the surface of the earth.  That has little to do with antenna range, unless the receiver is on the ground  at the horizon and you are talking about very high frequencies that to not follow the surface of the earth.